# How to fix profiling error "Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, profiling

When I attempt to run kernel profiling,  I get a series of `Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0` errors. I think it might be due to the profiler targeting a Fermi card, while there's a Kepler card in the machine. I'm using `Code Generation` `compute_30,sm_30`. How can I fix this error?

Environment:

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2010
- CUDA 4.2 + CUDA 5.0 (5.0 installed on top of 4.2)
- Occurs with projects created with the CUDA 5.0 wizard and with the 5.0 SDK samples. Also occurs with projects created with the 4.2 wizard. Both Debug and Release builds.
- GPUs: Single GTX660. (GTX570 was installed before but is no longer installed).
- Analysis Activity: Profile CUDA Application. Experiments to Run: All. Other settings on defaults.
- Nsight 2.2, bundled with CUDA 5.

Errors:

```
Nsight: Profiling Kernel kernel
Nsight:                 Achieved Occupancy Experiment ( 1/13):.
Nsight:                     Achieved Flops Experiment ( 2/13):.
Nsight:             Instruction Statistics Experiment ( 3/13):Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                   Issue Efficiency Experiment ( 4/13):Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                             Branch Experiment ( 5/13):..
Nsight:                      Memory Global Experiment ( 6/13):Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                       Memory Local Experiment ( 7/13):Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                     Memory Atomics Experiment ( 8/13):Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                      Memory Shared Experiment ( 9/13):Couldn't add counter: cta_launched_vsm0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                     Memory Texture Experiment (10/13):Couldn't add counter: tex0_cache_sector_misses_gpc0_tpc0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                      Memory Caches Experiment (11/13):..Couldn't add counter: l2_slice0_read_sectors_l1_fb0

Nsight:                 Memory Framebuffer Experiment (12/13):Couldn't add counter: l2_slice0_read_sysmem_sectors_fb0
(Not supported by device)
Nsight:                 Launch Information Experiment (13/13):.
Nsight: Experiments complete, total replays needed:  7
```

Comment: Can you provide the following information: (a) List of the GPUs installed in the machine. (b) Settings you selected in the Analysis Activity. (c) The device on which the kernel is executing. (d) Version of Nsight that you are using. Do you get the same error on SDK samples (matrixMul)? Roger, I know why this error would be printed but I don't know the cause. I may need you to post your question to the NVIDIA Forum so I can collect additional information.

Comment: @GregSmith: I added the information you requested. Thank you!

Comment: We were able to reproduce the error that you have on Nsight 2.2. Nsight 3.0 RC1 supports the GTX 660 and should resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nsight Visual Studio Edition 2.2 shipped before the GTX 660 (GK106) was released to market. Nsight 2.2 has been refreshed multiple times and works with drivers that are compatible with the GTX 660. However, the PM programming library was not updated for 2.2.

Nsight Visual Studio 3.0 RC1 available for download [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-nsight-visual-studio-edition) supports the GTX 660 and Tesla K20.

Comment: Worked perfectly on 3.0 RC1. Thank you.